# error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcframework

I am trying to create a .xcframework from a framework module, which consumes internally another obj-c framework. So I created bridging header to import obj-c header into swift framework. It is running well, but when I try to archive by

`xcodebuild archive -scheme module_name -destination="iOS" -archivePath /tmp/xcf/ios.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /tmp/iphoneos -sdk iphoneos SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES`

in terminal, i am getting error as

> error: using bridging headers with module interfaces is unsupported

How to resolve this?

Comment: Are you able to get rid of this issue?

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: @BoazSaragossi Yes, resolved this issue by adding those objective c framework's headers in Umbrella header file, instead Bridging header file

Comment: I'm having the same error but I'm not clear what (or where) my "Umbrella header" file would be? I'm trying to build a simple test of SwiftUI for a new branch of my app (re-skinning). The app uses my own custom Swift framework and quite a bit of third-party Obj-C/Obj-C++ code. Any help appreciated.